# Как правильно спроектировать базу данных?

Tags: sql

в качестве примера, есть 3 словаря русский, белорусский, украинский и 3 описания (или толкование) слов, т.е. когда выбирается русский язык и белорусский для описание (перевода) слова то прога ищет значение слова в таблице на белорусском, для примера на русском вводим слово 'рука' получаем описание на белорусском 'частка цела' (часть тела на белорусском языке).

примерно такой механизм, чтоб при смене языков скажем слово с белорусского получало описание на украинском, при поиске слова на украинском получало описание на русском и т.д.

как лучше организовать бд, на ум пришло только решение при котором создаю 3 таблицы для каждого языка (если добавятся новые языки новые таблицы и для них), 3 таблицы для каждого языка с описание слов, всего получается 6 таблиц (с каждым новым языком это цифра будет расти) как все это связать между собой? в правильном ли направлении я иду?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В правильном направлении идете. Вязать надо по ключевым полям, а для этого нужно прочитать учебник про нормализацию реляционных баз данных. Сейчас я думаю, Вам начнут ставить минусы. Чтобы этого не было, а был разговор по делу, было замечательно, если бы Вы приложили Ваш вариант диаграммы базы данных

Comment: добавил картинку схемы

Comment: как связать слово из каждого языка со значением из каждого языка, создать отдельные столбцы в таблицах с values?

Comment: Сразу подумайте, что будете делать со словами, имеющими несколько значений-описаний... особенно в случае, когда в разных языках эти наборы несимметричны.

Comment: думаю, но ничего на ум не приходит)

Comment: Убираю минус, нужно было сразу писать вопрос, так как он написан сейчас

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд правильно будет создать отдельную таблицу для языков. Пусть это будет таблица `Langs`. В нем будут столбцы `id`,`lang_code`.

А для слов уже будет не 3 таблицы а одна(с именем `Word`) с полями `id`, `word`, `lang`.

И как уже поняли связь между ними будет такой `Word.lang`=>`Langs.id`.

Идем дальше. Осталось таблица `Values` для описания. Эту таблицу то же оставим одну. А поля уже будут такими `id`, `value`, `word_id`. И как уже поняли связь между таблицами `Word` и `Values` будет такой `Values.word_id`=>`Word.id`.

И сейчас ваша база уже будет универсальной, и при добавлении нового языка вы не будете опять добавлять в базу новые таблицы. Вам нужно будет только в языковой таблице добавить новый язык. И все ваш новый язык к словарю будет готов.

Comment: получается все слова из всех языков будут в перемешку?

Comment: @MuscleCode Это не перемешка, все будут в одной таблице, и различить их надо при `lanc_code`. И это вообще то правильный подход, добавления нового языка и вообще вытаскивание из базы будет проще, Думаете при вашем подходе как вы будете всегда брать слова для каждого языка? С вашим подходом ваш код вытаскивания и сохранения будет больше и трудней.

Comment: если в дальнейшем нужно будет вытащить какие нибудь языки не станет ли это проблемой

Comment: @MuscleCode Вот как раз в такой базе ни каких проблем не будет